# Joomla, force render all tags

Tags: joomla, tags, render

In a blog_item I'm able to render tags with the following:

```
if ($params->get('show_tags', 1) && !empty($this->item->tags)) : 
  $this->item->tagLayout = new JLayoutFile('joomla.content.tags'); 
  echo $this->item->tagLayout->render($this->item->tags->itemTags); 
endif;
```

However, in one case I would need to render all available tags in a blog, without having a $this-item (since no item is selected)

Is there some way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: Use the Tags view, that gives a blog like layout of all tags.

Comment: I'm a Joomla newbie, so could you specify that somewhat? I tried also the following:  $layout = new JLayoutFile('joomla.content.tags'); echo $layout->render(); But it gives me "missing argument 1 for render".

Comment: Make a menu link. Select Tags, All Tags.That will show all the tags.   It would help probably if you would explain exactly what you want to acomplish.